# Customize Regular Expression

Tags: javascript, regex

This is my regular expression - /(\d{1,2}?h$)|(\d{1,2}h(?=\s+))/i

there is two 1.(\d{1,2}?h$) and 2.(\d{1,2}h(?=\s+) for same.
but difference is that first for end of string(h) and second for space after 'h'

i want to combine this two possibilities.

and when string is like 144h at that time it return 44h but i need null when there is more than two digits.

and i need single (combine) expression for 
1.strating of string 14h -: 14h at ahmedabad.
2.space before 14h string -: at ahmedabad 14h.
3.ending of string 14h -: at ahmedabad 14h
4.space after 14h string -: at ahmedabad 14h in meeting

Comment: Try to use this tool http://regexr.com// and build the regex easily..

Comment: Try to put a word boundary in front of your groups `\b`

Comment: finally its done!!!!!!!!!!!!                                                                                    ((^|\s)(\d{1,2})(h\s|h$)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is work.....

(^|\s)(\d{1,2})h(\s|$)

it match **23h in meeting** and **In meeting 23h**.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

> ^(\d{1,2}?h(\s){0,1})$

it will match 24h with 0 to 1 white space.

*^* and *$* are used as start and end of expression. So for *144h* you will get no matches.